# Print Before MPI_init

Tags: mpi

I am printing one statement before MPI_INIT. But it's not printing the message.

MPI.c

```
int x=25;
double T1;
print(" hello");
MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);  /* starts MPI */
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);  /* get current process id */
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size)
```

It's not printing any message

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because it's buffered. Try adding `\n`: `print(" hello\n");`. Or better flush the output buffer: `fflush(stdout);`.

`MPI_Init` affects MPI calls only. It does nothing with `printf`.